# auto fill-submit external form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, extjs, cross-domain

I'm working with a script to auto populate and submit an external form. The remote website seems to use Ext.Ajax.request to validate the form. My first attempt didn't work because of cross-domain issue : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' :(

code source of the remote form:

```
<form action="http://domain.com/loginaction.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    <input type="password" name="passwd" value=""/>
   <button id="submitbtn"  onclick="validate();">Log In</button>                      
</form>
```

validate() function is defined in js file.

Plz guys! what is the easiest way to send cross-domain requests?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [JQuery's $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to send data to a URL.

**Your HTML:**
I removed the action and method in the HTML, and moved them into the JavaScript.
Also, notice I added IDs (`id=""`) to the elements, so we can call them by using JQuery.

```
<form>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    <input id="pass" type="password" name="passwd" value=""/>
    <button id="submitbtn">Log In</button>
</form>
```

**Your JavaScript ([Using JQuery](http://jquery.com/)):**

```
// Call validateForm() when button is clicked

$("#submitbtn").on("click", validateForm);

function validateForm(){
    var inputName = $("#name").val(); // Get value of name
    var inputPass = $("#pass").val(); // Get value of pass

    // Make sure values aren't empty
    if(inputName != "" && inputPass != ""){ 

        // Assign values to parameters object
        var params = {
            "entry-1" : inputName,
            "entry-2" : inputPass
        };

        // Send the parameters to the selected URL
        var ajaxPost = $.ajax({
            url: "http://domain.com/loginaction.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: params
        });

        // What to do upon success
        ajaxPost.done(function(data, textStatus){
            console.log("Success!");
            console.log("data");
        });

        // What to do upon error
        ajaxPost.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log("Failure!");
            console.log("jqXHR");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work... always same error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource....

Comment: One other thing that I need to mention here is that I have no control over the remote website...

Comment: Oh, then it looks like the remote server isn't allowing you to submit your information because it's coming from an unknown source. It's a security feature to prevent unwanted access.